# Standalone SSDT installation only shows Integration Service in SSCM

Tags: reporting-services, ssis, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

I have installed SQL Server Data Tools in standalone mode (SSDT 2012 11.0.3000.0) i.e. without it being part of any SQL Server or Visual Studio Package. All I'm seeing now in SSCM is Integration Services running. There is no SSRS, SSAS or for that matter not even Database Engine and Agent services running. Even when I create any analysis or reporting service projects, all I see is SSIS toolbox over there. I haven't done this kind of standalone installation before and don't know if I might be missing something. Really appreciate some help here

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Provide links to what you installed and provide the Visual Studio version you are looking in. What version of SQL Server are you going to deploy to?

Comment: [SSDT 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843), but as I mentioned its build no. 11.0.3000.0. Its Visual Studio 2010 shell. I'm not going to install any SQL Server for now...my question is why am I not seeing any analysis or reporting services running.

Comment: your link installs the BI Dev tools inside Visual Studio 2012. Try looking there. The Visual Studio 2010 BI Dev tools come in the SQL Server 2012 install media only.

Comment: even I thought so...but its weird, I can only see VS 2010 shell. What surprises me is why even Database Engine services are not running.

Comment: So if you do Start... Run... "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" does it successfully open Visual Studio 2012? I wonder if you just are having trouble finding the right shortcut?

Comment: yup tried that...there is no Visual Studio 11.0, its Visual Studio 10.0, and clicking on devenv.exe again opens up that same shell

Comment: I would reinstall that link you provided if you want to develop on VS2012. Or get the SQL 2012 media and install the Dev tools for VS2010